# Text inside an image ATG

Tags: repository, media, atg, bcc

My requirement is to write internationalized text inside an image, Does ATG provides any OOTB functionality for the some. I have thought of using Media Repository in BCC , please suggest me an approach to achieve this in ATG

Answer (score 2):

ATG does not provide image manipulation OOTB.

There are two approaches for your problem:

- Create a `media` item for each one of the images. One image per language. This image will already have the text overlay embedded. You then have logic in your front-end (probably based on the ATG Multi-Site Architecture) to render the correct image for the correct language.
- Code one image into your page. Then retrieve some text (based on the language of the site you are viewing) and overlay this on the image using CSS.

Both of these have advantages and challenges and this approach is not specific to ATG.